# Equipotential and Work on Electric Charges at Rest

Tags: electrostatics, work, potential-energy, coulombs-law

Why exactly do lines of equal potential exist on a point charge at rest? This doesn't make sense to me if the point charge is hypothetically a lone charge undisturbed by other charges.

I'm reading Electromagnetism for Engineers by P. Hammond, and he wrote the equation:

$$\int _{\infty }^a\:-F\:dr\:=\:\frac{Q_1Q_2}{4\pi ε_0}\left[-\frac{1}{r}\right]_a^{\infty }$$

He said that the limits imply that the charge Q2 is brought from an infinite distance and that the negative sign in the front of F is put there to show that the work is done against the force.

I get the negative sign, but I still don't understand the bounds. Also, what exactly is a gradient? The book says that the electric field strength is the *gradient* of the electric potential and that its unit is the volt/meter. Please explain in layman's terms, I'm a freshman in undergrad.

Comment: You ask many questions here. Please limit your post to one, focused question.

Comment: Why make several posts?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that if the questions are not the same.